# Multithreaded access to a persistent linked list data structure

Tags: data-structures, concurrency, persistent-data-structure

I previously asked a question about persistent data structures [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10002/why-do-we-use-persistent-data-structures-in-functional-programming). After that I came across an [article that introduced persistent data structures](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9680/Persistent-Data-Structures). I have got a question on the following figure from the same article, where it describes how to implement a persistent linked list:

[image]

The author says:

> Inserting a new item into a persistent singly linked list will not
>   alter the existing list but create a new version with the item
>   inserted into it. Instead of copying the entire list and then
>   inserting the item into the copy, a better strategy is to reuse as
>   much of the old list as possible.

Since the two versions (Red and Yellow + Red) have common nodes (specifically, the last three Red nodes), how can one access these two versions simultaneously, for example in a multithreaded application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such list is intended to be immutable - the shared nodes will never be written to. There is no problem with several threads reading from the same memory location.